# how to get zero when data is not present for a particular field

Tags: sql, oracle

TABLE ABCD

```
   Group1  Class
      C1    A
      C2    A
      C3    B
      C4    C
      C1    A
```

Here i have table , im trying to get the folowing 
result

OUTPUT : (required in this  format using table ABCD

```
Group1  Class   Count
C1        A         2
C1        B         0
C1        C         0
C2        A         1
C2        B         0
C2        C         0
C3        A         0
C3        B         0
C3        C         1
```

I want to achieve this  using a query in sql . Thank you in advance , im quite new to queries wrt to oracle so please help me out with a query.

Comment: What kind of SQL is this?MS?My?

Comment: What SQL have you already tried?

Comment: please  let me know the reason  before  down voting please im quite new to posting doubts

Comment: Can you explain the logic?

Comment: the reason is you don't show us what you already tried and you don't specify the DBMS you're using

Comment: I don't understand what the query is supposed to do.

Comment: Where does (C1, B) come from?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy :  using the table  ABCD  i  want  get the output as  show  in the result

Comment: You'll need the carthesian product of two "calendar" tables (for Group and class), left joined to the original table.

Comment: @wildplasser : please  can  you a  code  snippet pls

Comment: Why isn't C4 not in the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the result. This creates a list of each `group1` and each `class`.  Once you have that list, then you can count how many match in your original table:

```
select s.group1, 
  s.class,
  count(d.class) tot
from 
(
  select distinct a.group1, c.class
  from abcd a
  cross join 
  (
    select distinct class
    from abcd
  ) c
) s
left join abcd d
  on s.group1 = d.group1
  and s.class = d.class
group by s.group1, s.class
order by s.group1, s.class;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd8c1/6)

Answer (score 0):

This works in sql server

```
SELECT O.*
    ,CASE WHEN I.[Group1] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Cnt
FROM Table1 I RIGHT JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.[Group1],T2.[Class] FROM Table1 T1
    CROSS JOIN  Table1 T2
) O ON I.[Group1] = O.[Group1] AND I.[Class] = O.[Class]
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de628/1)

**EDIT**

```
SELECT O.*
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN I.[Group1] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Cnt
FROM Table1 I RIGHT JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT T1.[Group1],T2.[Class] FROM Table1 T1
    CROSS JOIN  Table1 T2
) O ON I.[Group1] = O.[Group1] AND I.[Class] = O.[Class]
GROUP BY O.[Group1],O.[Class]
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25c34/2)

Comment: firstly thanks for the code snippet  ,  but i guess this works only if count is 0 or 1  . please  hlp me out if in case count increases

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question correctly, but I think you want something like this:

```
with all_combinations as (
  select distinct g.group1, c.class
  from (
    select group1
    from foobar
  ) g
    cross join (
      select class
      from foobar
  ) c
) 
select ac.group1, ac.class, count(f.group1)
from all_combinations ac
  left join foobar f on f.group1 = ac.group1 and f.class = ac.class
group by ac.group1, ac.class
order by ac.group1, ac.class
```

SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9be9f/1

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH  grp AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT grp AS grp FROM abcd
        )
,  cls AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT cls AS cls FROM abcd
        )
SELECT g.grp, c.cls
        , COALESCE(a.cnt, 0) AS the_count
FROM grp g
FULL OUTER JOIN cls c ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT grp, cls, COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM abcd
        GROUP BY grp,cls
        ) a ON a.grp = g.grp AND a.cls = c.cls
ORDER BY g.grp ,c.cls
        ;
```